# Where are all the chickens?

Tags: achievements, guild-wars-2

The Urban Battlefield Fractal in Guild Wars 2 has an ancillary achievement: Slay All the Chickens in the city. Because Kitties hate chickens, I assume.

But I'm going to be a little distracted dodging arrows, burning oil, ballista bolts, and who knows what else. Where are all the chickens hiding?

Comment: I've been able to confirm at least 5 chickens.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'm going off of memory when I got the achievement, but there should be five or six chickens.

There were two in the area you start in (courtyard), three within the city, and one in the final area where you fight the boss. I believe the chicken spawns are somewhat random so it may or may not help. What tripped me up was the achievement description which spoke of chickens being in the city...when there are chickens outside of the city walls.

Comment: There's 3 outside the city

Answer (score 0):

I've been in the fractal only once so far, so I don't know if their location is dynamic from run to run, but in my run, I've got the achievement before the second boss, the one in the town square. The chickens also weren't really hiding, they were running around on the street pretty much in plain sight. Most or all of them were in the streets after the the very first gate boss.

Comment: Do you know how many chickens there are, total?

Comment: @RavenDreamer Very few - just 5, I believe. And the achievement counts for the whole party as well, so it doesn't matter who kills them.

Comment: Do you have to kill the chickens *before* beating the fractal? I killed 5 chickens *after* but did not get an achievement.

Comment: @RavenDreamer We didn't actually beat the fractal, so all I can say is that killing them beforehand does count.